# Stack Calculator based on two stacks

Tags: c++, stack

I would like to make an algorithm based on two stacks, but my calcucator does not work well for the operator ')'. It should be on output the last of the numbers stack, but happens nothing when i add any ')'. Any suggestions?

We process further tokens until the end of the expression:

if we encounter a number, we put it back on the stack of values

if we encounter an operator, we put it on the operator stack

if we encounter an opening parenthesis, we do nothing

if we encounter a closing bracket, then:

1. we take off the operator and two values from the stack
2. we calculate the value of the expression
3. we put the result on the stack of values

The calculated value of the expression is on the stack

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string c;
    stack<int>numbers;
    stack<char>operators;
    cin >> c;
    string expression(c);
    for(unsigned int i =0; i <expression.size(); i++)
    {
        if( expression[i] >= 48 && expression[i] <= 57 )
        {
            numbers.push(expression[i]);
        }
        else if(expression[i] == '(')
        {
        ;
        }
        else if(expression[i] == '+')
        {
            operators.push(expression[i]);
        }
        else if(expression[i] ==  '-')
        {
            operators.push(expression[i]);
        }
        else if(expression[i] == '*')
        {
            operators.push(expression[i]);
        }
        else if(expression[i] == '/')
        {
            operators.push(expression[i]);
        }
        else if(expression[i] == ')' )
        {
            if(operators.top()== '+')
            {
                int a,b, score;
                a = numbers.top() - '0';
                numbers.pop();
                b = numbers.top() - '0';
                numbers.pop();
                score = a+b;
                numbers.push(score);
                operators.pop();
            }
            else if(operators.top()== '-')
            {
                int a,b, score;
                a = numbers.top() - '0';
                numbers.pop();
                b = numbers.top() - '0';
                numbers.pop();
                score = b-a;
                numbers.push(score);
                operators.pop();
            }
            else if(operators.top()== '*')
            {
                int a,b, score;
                a = numbers.top()- '0';
                numbers.pop();
                b = numbers.top()- '0';
                numbers.pop();
                score = a*b;
                numbers.push(score);
                operators.pop();
            }
            else if(operators.top()== '/')
            {
                int a,b, score;
                a = numbers.top()- '0';
                numbers.pop();
                b = numbers.top()- '0';
                numbers.pop();
                score = b/a;
                numbers.push(score);
                operators.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    cout << numbers.top()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to handle simple things like `5 + 7 * 3`?  Or if no parentheses are encountered?  I think those aspects are totally missing from your code and one reason why your code doesn't really work.  Think of those scenarios, and your code would come closer to producing the right answer.

Comment: I've change my code and now it does work only for one bracket, even on paper step by step should be correct.

Comment: Why not actually push the left parenthesis onto the operator stack?  The way this should work is that each item that is pushed on the stack has a precedence level -- a left paren has the highest precedence level, thus is always pushed onto the stack.  The right paren always has the lowest precedence level, so it acts as the "stack popping starter".  I think the issue is that you are not aware or are not writing the correct way to evaluate an expression using a stack.  The fact you ignored precedence levels on your operators suggests that you're missing the fundamentals of implementing this.

Comment: In other words, if you encounter the right paren, you evaluate everything in the stack (pop) until you hit the left paren (which should be in the stack, but your code completely ignores it by having a do-nothing `;` in the `if` statement for the left paren).

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issues with the code are:

1. This will only work for single digit numbers (you treat each character as a different number)
2. The fact that numbers is a char stack limits the number to the size of a char. Due to (1) that limit is not really a problem, but when you try to print it at the end the char value will be treated a string encoding. If numbers were a tack of ints instead, it would be converted to the base 10 representation we all know and love when printed.
3. The order of the operands is wrong (when you unstack them you get the reverse of what you stacked). This is particularly problematic for divisions and subtractions.

Moving forward you may want to have a tokenizer phase that will abstract away some of the details of the text representation to your calculator. Also, be mindful of preserving the order of the operands (eg. change `score = x-y` to `score = y-x`).

Comment: I've change my code and now it works good, but only for one parenthesis. If i do (2*(2+4)) it gives me -84.